# Unable to display secondary Form as a MainForm

Tags: c++, c++builder

So I have this issue with C++ Builder. I have a project containing two simple forms, and nothing more.

This resulted as the following generated code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
USEFORM("testUnit1.cpp", Form1);
USEFORM("bluewin.cpp", Form2);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I get it, the first created form (Form1) was assigned as the MainForm and is displayed at execution. This works and only Form1 is displayed.

Now I want to display the second form (Form2) and only this one. I read that inverting the two lines:

```
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);
```

to obtain

```
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
```

should do the trick but it doesn't. Actually both forms are displayed. i tried setting the MainForm to Form2 by going to Project > Options > Forms, but I obtain the same result.

Any idea why this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MainForm is the 1st `TForm` instantiated with `Application->CreateForm()` at runtime. Setting the MainForm in the Project Options merely changes the order of the `CreateForm()` calls in the code. So swapping the calls is the correct solution.

If Form1 is still being displayed when Form2 is the MainForm, it is because you left Form1's `Visible` property set to true at design-time. Set it to false instead. And then you can call `Form1->Show()` or `Form1->ShowModal()` whenever you are actually ready to display it.

When a non-MainForm `TForm` is created in the IDE and added to the project, it is set to `Visible=false` initially.